# Using というのは in [PERSON A]，もしかして，あの人は一緒に，というのは，[PERSON B]

Tags: grammar, usage

I am trying to write an ambiguous/evasive sentence.
The sentence is:

> [PERSON A]，もしかして，あの人は一緒に，というのは，[PERSON B]ー

To the effect of "Person A, is it possible, that you and *that person*, that is to say, Person B-"

Am I using this correctly or is there another, more suitable word to use? I want to keep the comedic disjunction of the sentence without sacrificing the meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think the first part is enough if you want to create some ambiguity. So you can say :

- [PERSON A]、 もしかして、 [PERSON B]と一緒に...

This sentence is enough to be evasive. Also, you can replace もしかして by まさか if you want the sentence to have a stronger suggestion of the meaning (I feel like, in this case, まさか is better).